# I am wondering what many of which refers to?

Tags: clauses

Original: -ant also occurs in adjectives, many of which are formed from stems which are not current words in English.

Would you please tell me if I have properly rephrased the above sentence? and what does many refer to?

-ant also occurs in adjectives many of which are formed from stems which are not current words in English.

In addition, would you possibly write the bold part in another form?

-ant also occurs in adjectives, **many of which are formed** from stems which are not current words in English.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **many of which** refers to **adjectives**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite without the comma: don't do it. The comma should be there. *Many of which* refers to *adjectives*.

As for your second question:

> -ant also occurs in adjectives. Many of these adjectives are formed from stems which are not current words in English.

Comment: ant also occurs in adjectives, of which many are formed from stems which are not current words in English.
is this also possible?

Comment: what about this?-ant also occurs in adjectives, whose many are formed from stems which are not current words in English.

Comment: _of which many_ is possible, but less idiomatic. _Whose many_ is simply wrong. Even if you could use _whose_, the question is _whose many **what?** are formed_. You're missing a subject in your sentence then.